# Media Queries to Change Image

Tags: html, css, image, media-queries

I am designing a website which works on desktops and mobile devices, using [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp). For the most part, this is working fine. However, I have a scenario which I will attempt to describe below, which is not working properly.

On a desktop, I have a series of images with text overlay, arranged as so:

[image: desktop plan]

On a mobile, I would like this displayed in two columns with the final tile being spread across the full width, as so:

[image: mobile plan]

However, the image I use for the final tile on the desktop is square, and when I spread it across the full width, it is way too big and looks more like this:

[image: mobile actual]

Below is the HTML and CSS that I have at the moment:

```
<div>
    <div class="hotel_container">
        <div class="options">
            <div class="option">
                <a href="www.example.com" target="_blank"><img class="opt_img" src="images/example.jpg"></a>
                <h3 class="centered" id="hotel_info">TEXT</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- repeated "options" div 7 more times -->
        <div class="options_last">
            <div class="option">
                <a href="www.example.com" target="_blank"><img class="opt_img" src="images/example2.jpg"></a>
                <h3 class="centered" id="hotel_info">TEXT</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

CSS

```
.options, .options_last{
    width: 33%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 812px) {
    .options{
        width: 50%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 812px) {
    .options_last{
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.option{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 812px) {
    .option{
        padding: 1px;
    }
}

.opt_img{
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.opt_img:hover{
    opacity: 0.9;
}

.centered {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#hotel_info{
    background-color: rgba(130, 130, 130,0.7);
    width: 80%;
    font-size: 23px;
    padding: 15px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 812px) {
    #hotel_info{
        width: 60%;
        font-size: 10px;
        padding: 5px;
    }
}
```

I do not want to force the image to be a certain height as this would distort it, so instead I thought I could have a second image, which is rectangular, which I could switch in when on mobile. However, I cannot for the life of me work out how to select a different picture based on the device, as I would with a traditional media query.

[Edit: I am aware of the ability to have both images on the page and hide one or the other with media queries but have been warned that this can slow pages down if overused as all devices have to load all the images. I am looking for a 'better' way to do this, to avoid picking up bad habits while I'm learning on something small scale]

Can someone give me a hand, or point me towards a simple explanation online that may help me figure this out please.

---

P.S. I am very new to web development so please make your answers beginner friendly, and bear with me if I have to ask for clarification. I am also open to suggestions of better or simpler ways of doing things, I am working with what I have learnt from the Codecademy courses on web development.

Comment: How is your HTML markup being generated? Is this hand coded or do you have some sort of PHP that's creating the HTML? If you are hand coding it, you simply just add another image with the dimensions you want to the last block and hide it on desktop using your media queries.

Comment: @disinfor I am hand coding it all. I have heard of that technique but was warned that it would cause pages to load slower as it has to load both images on all devices. On something of my scale, it probably wouldn't be noticeable but I am curious as to whether there is a 'better' way, so I don't pick up bad habits while still learning

Comment: You may be able to use srcset to pick which image sto show as described by [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-css/). They show an example like so `<img
  sizes="(min-width: 400px) 80vw, 100vw"
  srcset="examples/images/small.jpg 375w,
          examples/images/big.jpg 1500w"
  alt="…">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply put a rectangular image and hide it on screens above than mobile, common media query breakpoints most people use is the bootstrap way: 0 to 768px for mobile devices, 768px to 992px for tablets and similar devices, 992px to 1200px for medium screens and above 1200px for large screens like Apple retina and 4K.

In this situation, you can add a class like `.show-sm` and `.hidden-sm` and use it for your purposes:

Example for showing element just on mobile:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .hidden-sm {
        display: none !important; // use important to override other styles
    }
    .show-sm {
        display: block !important; // use important to override other styles
    }
}
```

Example for showing element for above mobile resolution:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .hidden-sm {
        display: block !important; // use important to override other styles
    }
    .show-sm {
        display: none !important; // use important to override other styles
    }
}
```

And add these classes to elements you want to show and hide on mobile and desktop, for example:

```
<div>
    <div class="hotel_container">
        <!-- show this element just on desktop -->
        <div class="options hidden-sm">
            <div class="option">
                <a href="www.example.com" target="_blank"><img class="opt_img" src="images/example.jpg"></a>
                <h3 class="centered" id="hotel_info">TEXT</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- show this element just on mobile -->
        <div class="options_last show-sm">
            <div class="option">
                <a href="www.example.com" target="_blank"><img class="opt_img" src="images/example2.jpg"></a>
                <h3 class="centered" id="hotel_info">TEXT</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

And last but not the least, you can use media queries for applying styles between two resolutions, for example:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px) {
    .hidden-md {
        display: none !important; // use important to override other styles
    }
}
```

As you see, his media query works between 768px and 992px and hides the element with declared class.
Hope it helps.

**PS:** You can declare your own media queries, with your custom resolutions as your needs and unlimited.

**PS 2:** Also make sure to have viewport meta in your head tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: I've seen this suggested before but people have said that this causes pages to load slowly as it has to load both images on all devices. On something of the scale I'm making, it probably won't make a noticeable difference, but I would be interested to know if there was a 'better' way of doing it, so I don't pick up bad habits at this early stage of learning

Comment: Actually, this is the most common CSS media query way and it's answer to your question, you can use CSS background images but as you know it's a bad practice. Also using Ajax to load another image on screen change is another way, and it's a bad way too :)

Comment: Fair enough, thank you then. At least I can be happy in the knowledge that I'm not picking up bad habits!

Comment: You're welcome. I forgot to mention that you can put your image on a figure or div tag, and use absolute positioning to put the image absolutely into the container, then resize the div on screen change, and reposition image by CSS. But it depends on your image content and composition.

Comment: @lioness99a if an element has display none it will not load any resources until display is visible (block, inline, etc)

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Ah, I didn't know that, thanks! Web dev is such a complicated space when you're just starting out!

Answer (score 3):

You could try using the [clip property in CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp).

```css
.clippable {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0px,250px,100px,0px);
}

.flex-flow {
  align-self: auto;
  
}

.flow-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 250px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="flow-box">
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/883859744498176000/pjEHfbdn_400x400.jpg" width="100" height="100" class="flex-flow"/>
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/883859744498176000/pjEHfbdn_400x400.jpg" width="100" height="100" class="flex-flow"/>
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/883859744498176000/pjEHfbdn_400x400.jpg" width="100" height="100" class="flex-flow"/>
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/883859744498176000/pjEHfbdn_400x400.jpg" width="100" height="100" class="flex-flow"/>
</div>

  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/883859744498176000/pjEHfbdn_400x400.jpg" width="250" height="250" class="clippable"/>
```

Comment: Thanks - this might come in handy with a different picture of mine actually! The one I describe in this question can't be clipped or it would lose meaningful information but I have another similar situation with a repeating pattern :D